# Can't read $this->post('username'); in rest server from input form rest client

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, restful-url

Why `$this->post('username')` can not read input from rest client ?

In my controller for server :

```
function login_post(){
    $data['username']=$this->post('username');
    $data['password']=$this->post('password');

    if ($this->get('cobak')==1) { 
         $cek = $this->model_user->ambilPengguna($data);
    }

    if ($cek) {
         $this->response($cek, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code}
    else {
         $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
    }
}
```

My models :

```
public function ambilPengguna($data) {
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('tbl_user');
     $this->db->where($data);
     $query = $this->db->get();

     return $query->num_rows();
}
```

And this is my client controller :

```
public function proses_login(){ 
    $data = array(  
         'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 
         'password' => $this->input->post('password')
     ); 
    $cek = $this->rest->post('login/cobak/1/format/php/'); 
    echo $cek;
}
```

The result from query is 5. It means read all record in database table

Answer (score 0):

You send data by URL method you can send data instead as the following
for more information about URL method you can **[read this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)**

```
$cek = $this->rest->post('login', $data, 'php');
```

you can recieve  data in server by two ways

```
$this->post('username') or $this->input->post('username')
```

I think it may work

you can get more details from : **[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)**